# Как создать новую консоль в дочернем процессе "Child"?

Tags: windows, c, процесс

Я поставил флаг - `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` в атрибутах `CreateProcess`, но при отладке новая консоль не отображается.
Само задание:   Создать дочерний процесс Child (добавить к рабочей области еще один консольный вид проекта, при создании дочернего процесса отвести ему новую консоль) .

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    //Создание дочернего процесса
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess, saThread;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessB;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    lstrcpy(szPath, TEXT("Parents"));
    CreateProcess(NULL, szPath, &saProcess, &saThread, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &piProcessB);
    saProcess.nLength = sizeof(saProcess);
    saProcess.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    saProcess.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saThread.nLength = sizeof(saThread);
    saThread.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    saThread.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    lstrcpy(szPath, TEXT("Child"));
    CreateProcess(NULL, szPath, &saProcess, &saThread, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &piProcessB);
    GetLastError();
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль должен заказать сам дочерний процесс. (Для этого проще всего откомпилировать его как консольное приложение, консоль появится автоматически.) Вы не сможете флагами запуска заставить её появиться. К примеру, как бы вы не запускали Notepad.exe, консоль не появится.

Флаг `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` делает [не совсем то](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863.aspx), что вы думаете. Он просто означает, что *если* запускаемое приложение закажет себе консольное окно, это окно должно быть не унаследовано от вашего процесса (как бывает, если запускать, к примеру, утилиты командной строки из-под cmd.exe), а создано вновь (по есть будет два окна). Вот.

---

Дополнение: в вашем вопросе сказано, что child вы компилируете сами. Тогда сделайте вот что:

- Убедитесь, что вы компилируете его как консольное приложение.
- Убедитесь, что процесс запускается без ошибок. Не игнорируйте возвращаемое значение функций `CreateProcess` и `GetLastError`!
- Выведите какую-нибудь строку в функции main программы child и посмотрите, в какую консоль она выведется.

Comment: @VladD, тогда что можно сделать, чтобы вывести для "Child" новую консоль?

Comment: @AlexC: если Child -- ваша программа, то просто скомпилируйте её как консольное приложение. Если не ваша, ничего сделать нельзя.

Comment: @VladD Запустить cmd.exe, а Child -- в параметры, вместе с ключом `/C`

     cmd.exe /C Child

Если не забыл. Виндов под рукой нет.

Comment: @alexlz: но это запустит не child, а cmd.exe. Причём и консольное окно будет у cmd.exe, а не у программы, которую этот самый cmd.exe запустит.

Comment: > Если не ваша, ничего сделать нельзя.

Не совсем верно. Можно в PE заголовке изменить subsystem на console, тогда при запуске того же блокнота будет появляться еще и окошко консоли, но в эту консоль конечно же ничего писаться не будет.

Comment: @insolor: если вы подменили программу, то вы запускаете не Child, а что-то "левое". Не важно, изменили вы 1 байт или все.

Comment: @VladD, чем по-вашему отличается замена 1 байта от перекомпиляции (правовые вопросы не рассматриваем)?

Comment: @insolor: не совсем понял вопрос. Замена одного байта легче, чем перекомпиляция -- да. Та ли это программа после замены -- нет. (Кстати, если заменить случайный байт в коде, у программы хороший шанс крешнуться.) Программы, подписанные криптографическим ключом, могут после замены байта и не запуститься.

Comment: > Та ли это программа после замены -- нет.

Пользователи ломаного ПО с вами не согласятся)

Comment: @insolor т.е. они вполне согласны произвести обратный обмен? Русифицированного на оригинальное?

Comment: @alexlz, скажем так, они взаимозаменяемы, что бы не думали об этом пользователи)